# How to cast Hive's LazyPrimitive objects to java primitive objects?

Tags: java, hive

Is there a way to cast Hive Lazy Objects to Java Objects. For example : LazyDouble to Double?

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do it directly by casting.
But you can call `getObject()` on it.
This method is inherited from `LazyPrimitive`.

Comment: Thanks Peter. This is what I also found out. I am trying to send the data to a remote system from a hive udf so thought of casting them to a Java primitive type, serialize and send it to a remote application so that I wouldn't have to use any Hive jars on the remote end. I'll see if I could find a workaround for this problem.